# why git clone failed when using HTTPS but succeed using git protocol

Tags: git

I use git client in linux command line without using any http proxy to clone `https://git.gnome.org/m4-common/` but get failed:

```
% git clone https://git.gnome.org/m4-common/
Cloning into 'm4-common'...
fatal: repository 'https://git.gnome.org/m4-common/' not found
```

It's no problem with `git://git.gnome.org/m4-common/`

```
% git clone git://git.gnome.org/m4-common/
...
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links are at the [bottom of the page](https://git.gnome.org//browse/m4-common/):

```
git://git.gnome.org/m4-common
```

and

```
https://git.gnome.org/browse/m4-common
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation for Git in GNOME](https://wiki.gnome.org/Git/Developers):

> With Git 1.6.6 and newer, http is possible too (please use the git protocol though!):
>
> git clone [http://git.gnome.org/browse/[project]](http://git.gnome.org/browse/%5Bproject%5D)

From this I take it that you need Git version `1.6.6` or later.  Also, it appears that you should be using `http` and not `https`.